# Android Error ,Gradle Builed successfull，running crash

Tags: windows

> E/dalvikvm: Could not find class
>   'android.graphics.drawable.RippleDrawable', referenced from method
>   android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatImageHelper.hasOverlappingRendering
>   E/OpenGLRenderer: Getting MAX_TEXTURE_SIZE from GradienCache
>   E/OpenGLRenderer: MAX_TEXTURE_SIZE: 16384 E/OpenGLRenderer: Getting
>   MAX_TEXTURE_SIZE from Caches::initConstraints() E/OpenGLRenderer:
>   MAX_TEXTURE_SIZE: 16384 A/libc: Fatal signal 11 (SIGSEGV) at
>   0x00000000 (code=1), thread 8126 (dking.mygifview)